# Segue from objective c to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to segue from an Objective C view controller to a Swift one, and also pass data to the new view controller.

In Objective C, I would:

```
#include "SecondViewController.h"

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   SecondViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];
   svc.property = self.property;
}
```

How do I accomplish the same when segueing to a Swift view controller?

I've tried including "SecondViewController.swift", but that only introduced errors and wouldn't allow me to use *SecondViewController *svc* in PrepareForSegue: anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the swift bridge header file, which has name `<module_name>_Swift.h`. For example, if your project is called `MyProject`:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

Note that this is **not** the bridging header used to expose objc code to swift, named `<module_name>-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: That file only contains:

//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

Comment: You are looking at the bridging header, he really meant the Xcode generated header. It is not visible from Xcode but should be imported as specified above. Read the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Thanks @bjtitus - user2055369, that file is not listed in the project navigator, but you can open by cmd+click its name from the import statement. It contains an objective c representation of your swift code, so in order to access a swift class from obj-c you need to #import it

Comment: Yes. Thank you. All very helpful. Apple's documentation was unclear and Xcode doesn't autocomplete MyProject-Swift.h so it's all rather confusing.

Comment: Yes, it works but I see no way to mark this as "answered". I'll also be posting a follow up question later tonight.

Comment: @user2055369 there should be a gray checkmark below the up/down buttons, at the left side of the answer - don't remember if there's a min time interval for users with low reputation score. Also if it was you downvoting the answer, I would appreciate if you could at least undo the downvote :)