# How can I pass an NSInteger from objective c view controller to a swift one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

As a follow up to: [Segue from objective c to swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149650/segue-from-objective-c-to-swift)

Now that I can pass data to the swift class, I seem to limited in what kind of data I can pass.

I am unable to pass an integer, only other types.

Looking at MyProject-Swift.h, none of the *var XXXX: NSInteger!* are listed there.

Currently I have to convert the number to a string in objective c, pass that string, and then convert it back into a number in swift.

Is there a number format I can declare in swift that will be accessible in objective c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in NSNumber: `var nsNumber = NSNumber(someValue);`

NSNumber is accessible in both ObjC and Swift.